# How get Application Id on Samza worker?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, apache-samza

I don't need "container id" or "App Attempt Id".

On the [documentation](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.10/jobs/logging.html) I see we can put `${samza.log.dir}` for the log4j config and this path contain the application id. It's like `/foo/log/../application_id_123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, if you know an better solution you can reply.

```
 final String samzaLogDir = System.getProperty("samza.log.dir");
 final String[] samzaLogDirSplit = samzaLogDir.split("/");
 final String applicationId = samzaLogDirSplit[samzaLogDirSplit.length - 2];
```

Comment: and get the container name : System.getProperty("samza.container.name");